# jquery slideshow issue with buttons

Tags: jquery, html, show, carousel, slide

i am using a jquery carousel on a new page i am creating.

i tested it on localhost at first, and it was working properly,but on my server wasnt appearing at first load. then i changed this $(function() with this $(window).load(function() and the slideshow loads ok.
the actual problem is that
the slideshow is working properly on localhost, but when i tested it on my server the slideshow buttons are missing!

the url is this marketstrom.reload-it.gr

any ideas?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking your site, I see that the images are not loaded (404).
In details:

- http://marketstrom.reload-it.gr/images/brbl.png
- http://marketstrom.reload-it.gr/images/playpause.gif
- http://marketstrom.reload-it.gr/images/caption.gif

You should fix these references and then should work.

Answer (score 0):

The URL of your buttons' background image (defined in CSS) is

```
http://marketstrom.reload-it.gr/images/brbl.png
```

But there is no such image at that location. Try uploading your `brbl.png` to the images directory.